# catalog price rules automaticaly removed after 12:00 am everyday when date change

Tags: catalog-price-rules, date, price-rules

I have been applied Catalog price rules on some categories from some DATE to some DATE and it works OK but when date change on every midnight the rules are disable. i don't know why its happen please guide me anyone how to fix that

Answer (score 1):

You have not configured your Magento cron. This will run nightly to reapply rules as necessary.

Add this to your crontab

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/cron.sh
```

Comment: */5*****/path/to/cron.sh or just */5***** ??